# Build generated from adapter-node is not working on Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';

import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import firebase from "svelte-adapter-firebase";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()  + firebase(),
    },
    preprocess: vitePreprocess()
    
};


export default config;
```

when running npm build on Svelte it ios throwing an error:
config.kit.adapter should be an object with an "adapt" method, rather than the name of an adapter.

Comment: Have you tried the snippet in the [Setup part of the `svelte-adapter-firebase` documentation](https://github.com/jthegedus/svelte-adapter-firebase#setup)? You don't need two adapters, and you can't add them together like that.

Comment: build seems to be working now, but do not get it properly deployed on Firebase

Comment: issue remains, still getting error: Node.js v18.8.0
[vite-plugin-sveltekit-compile] Prerendering failed with code 1
error during build:
Error: Prerendering failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/User/my-CV/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/index.js:551:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

not sure if this has sovlved the issue. I want to choose Firebase